# How can I add two for loop list to one?

Tags: python

So, I creating two list with a for loop, but I don't know how can I add them together.

```
    def month_changed(cls):

    df = pd.read_excel("income.xlsx")
    df1 = df.iloc[:13].values

    for x in range(12):
        try:
            df2 = sum(int(i) for i in df1[x, 1:])
            mylist = [df2]
            print(mylist)

        except ValueError:
            print("cannot convert float NaN to integer")
```

output: `[21288] [21445]`

desired output: `[21288,21445]`

Any idea?

Comment: with `mylist` you create every time a list and print it. why do you expect to have one big list? try to append elements if you want only one list

Comment: "I mean my loop is an int(or float) object" This does not make any sense at all. Please try to think more clearly and logically about the code, and about the meanings of the words. Anyway, to append elements to a list, you need for the list to exist already. `mylist = [df2]` means "make a **new** list, **right now**, with **one** element `df2`; then use `mylist` as the name for it". "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'" Think about what you want to append, and what you want to append it *to*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that a lot easier than looping through lists. You already have the dataframe df1 after `pd.read_csv`.

```
df1['sum'] = df1[df1.columns[1:]].sum(axis=1)
# 'sum' will be new column
# df1[df1.columns[1:]] will skip the first column
# sum(axis=1) will add all values together along the axis (horizontally)
# df1['sum'] is a pd.Series, if you want a list just do:
result_list = df1['sum'].tolist()

print(result_list)
e.g [1,23,35,57]
#since you have 13 rows, this list should have 13 elements
```

EDIT:
just to show you how you would get your code working, only little changings.
I created a little test dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'dummy': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3},
     'col1': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 3.2, 3: 3.0},
     'col2': {0: 2.4, 1: 3.0, 2: 4.5, 3: 7.0},
     'col3': {0: 12.3, 1: 11.0, 2: 1.7, 3: 3.3}})

result_sum1, result_sum2, result_sum3 = [], [], []
for x in range(len(df)):
    try:
        # 2 examples how you get your sum
        row_sum1 = sum(int(i) for i in df.iloc[x, 1:])
        row_sum2 = sum(map(int, df.iloc[x, 1:]))
        
        # if you leave it with floats just do:
        row_sum3 = sum(df.iloc[x, 1:])
        
        result_sum1.append(row_sum1)
        result_sum2.append(row_sum2)
        result_sum3.append(row_sum3)
    except ValueError:
        print("cannot convert float NaN to integer")
        
print(f"1: {result_sum1}")
print(f"2: {result_sum2}")
print(f"3: {result_sum3}")

[15, 15, 8, 13]
[15, 15, 8, 13]
[15.700000000000001, 15.0, 9.4, 13.3]
```

Comment: I tried it. I get the following error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'  but thanks! your code looks so much better!

Comment: it working. I just had to rename df1 to df, because df1 where I used to Iloc my values.

Comment: how about you provide some more of your code (why do you have an array? nothing in your shown code indicates that). and if you give a little sample of your data we take a look?

Comment: @sandor I edited my answer again with your the corrected code from you

Comment: thank you!  I tried to make my code working for hours. I'm starting to think that I'm just stupid and programming isn't for me.

Comment: I think I'll stick with your original one. so much shorter.

Comment: yes. very recommended. try to avoid looping through rows of a dataframe. Most things are covered by pandas that do that in an optimized way for you, you just need to search for it ;)